# Unknown option: '--target', Unknown option: '--environment'; while trying to build ng app in prod

Tags: angular, typescript, build, ng-build

Tried to build the angular app in prod mode, but unknown target and environment error found.

Tried with below:

```
ng build --target=production --base-href /
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
ng build --prod --env=prod
```

I expected build files like main.js, vendor.js etc..
The out put was :

```
Unknown option: '--target'
Unknown option: '--environment'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ng build --configuration=staging
ng server --configuration=staging
```

Ensure you create a `environment.staging` file in environment folder and also modified the `angular.json` file to allow this command.

```
"build": {
"production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
}
    

"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "letsfarm-frontend:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "letsfarm-frontend:build:production"
        },
        "staging": {
          "browserTarget": "letsfarm-frontend:build:staging"
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this build command
`ng build --base-href="/" --env=prod`

Answer (score 1):

ng build --prod is the default building command for production environment, no need to other parameters, only if there is sth specific you need to achieve 
For example If you have another environment you can run

`ng build --c= staging` where c stand for configuration
here is further options 
https://angular.io/cli/build

Answer (score 0):

Found that below command executes well without any arguments:

```
ng build --prod
```

Output:

```
Date: 2019-04-02T05:51:07.034Z
Hash: 13d7def367e6ab28002d
Time: 126225ms
chunk {0} runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} es2015-polyfills.c5dd28b362270c767b34.js (es2015-polyfills) 56.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.ab6e55257ccc1317a780.js (main) 245 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js (polyfills) 41 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.b0dcfc0155d6280ef171.css (styles) 488 kB [initial] [rendered]
```